# The Vedas - where to start and how to start

Tags: scripture, vedas

I want to read, understand and comprehend The Vedas, but I do not know about the mystical or nuanced aspects of the language and terms used in these hymns. Kindly suggest me with good resources to explain these.

Regards.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.